# How can I use Multiple -web-kit filters in a single JQuery function?

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to utilize HTML sliders and respond to changes by applying webkit filters through JQuery. I've managed to get a single style applied and work as shown in the link below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxLWm.jpg

The documentation says doing it like this will work:

```
css({"propertyname":"value","propertyname":"value",...});
```

Here is my code of the opacity slider AFTER I do what is suggested by w3.

```
    $("#sliderOpacity").on("input", function(){
    $("#numOpacity").text($("#sliderOpacity").val());
    opacity = $("#sliderOpacity").val();
    $("#imgManipulated img").css({"-webkit-filter" : "opacity("+opacity*.01+")", "-webkit-filter" : "saturate("+$("#sliderSaturation").val()*.01+")"})
});
```

Both sliders are returning correct values.

It will only apply the second "saturate" style to the image and not the opacity. In fact, the opacity doesn't even change now. Since it's on the OPACITY slider, I do not expect to see saturation changes, only opacity.

This is another GIF of what it looks like with the code they suggest. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIEvt.jpg

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to make it like `-webkit-filter: opacity() saturate()` ?  If so, put them both in a single string that you give to the key.

Comment: You just need to give it a single key value pair.  You already understand concatenation by your use of `+` in your example.  So just give it a single key and combine your two values into a single string with concatenation.

Comment: @Taplar Oh my gosh that was incredibly easy. I've been staring at this screen for way too long I guess. Thanks for the help!